# excel(xlsx) string replace using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to replace strings in several Excel files using python.

I'm trying to do it in bulk, and also I'm not sure about the regularity of a string that I want to replace...

first, I get the list of file names below to obtain filenames excluding ".xlsx"(I intentionally exclude .xlsx for other purposes)
from C:\Users\username\Desktop\file\pro

```
import openpyxl
import os
from os import walk

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\file')
pro = 'pro//'
extension = ('.xlsx')
filenames = next(walk(pro)), (None, None, []))[2]  

filelist = []
for i in filenames:
    new = i.replace(extension, "")
    filelist.append(new)
```

Then I iterate each file to find the string I want to replace

```
replacer = "=[1]!BError"

for i in filelist:
    filename = i + extension
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(pro+filename)
    ws = wb["Val"]    

    for r in range(1, ws.max_row + 1):
       for c in range(1, ws.max_column + 1):
           s = str(ws.cell(r, c).value)

           if s != None and replacer in s:
               ws.cell(r, c).value = s.replace(replacer,'=')

    wb.save(i + extension)
```

The above only works if the string is exactly "=[1]!BError" but the problem is, the number between brackets varies from 1~50. The number is the same for every cell in one particular file, but different in each file.

And sometimes it could be very weird like
="_xlfn.SINGLE([11]!BError"

Is there any way that I can replace strings of "=~~~~~!BError"  into "=" regardless of what's in ~~~~ is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If “!Berror” is the common part of all the strings you want to replace just write that in replacer variable. That way the “in” key word will catch it in your if statement.

Comment: I can't do that because I want to replace from '=~~!Berror' As a whole to only '='

Comment: then get rid of the .replace method on the last line and just assign the "=" to cell value. like so: | ws.cell(r, c).value = '=' |

Comment: Sorry for nonclear explanation but cell contains formula after Berror for example  "=[11]Berror'(IF (A1 = "", "", B1)" And I need it to be "=(IF(A1 = "","",B1)"